# Use Netty as a client from behind a proxy?

Tags: java, networking, netty

I want to write a client based on Netty that connects to a server. The client will be running behind a corporate firewall with a HTTP proxy.

I can not find any info if Netty supports connections over proxies OOB or not.

In previously situations when I have written clients I always end up doing this support myself when the socket is created but with Netty beeing a popular framework I was hoping that it would support connection over proxies.

(The protocol I shall implement is not based on HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle it by yourself and write the proper handling for the protocol you want to use.

Comment: is this possible now in netty 4.1.17?